# How to use volume keys to change not-master volume up-down in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

I have a USB soundcard with Toslink (S/PDIF) output under Windows 10 and as such master volume does nothing. Looking at [Audio quality via S/PDIF](https://superuser.com/q/347086/41259) this is not at all unexpected. I can control the volume in, say, YouTube if I change the volume up-down in their video player. My keyboard has volume up-down keys. How could I use them to change the volume of the currently playing channel instead of master? Or perhaps all channels.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Nir Sofer's SoundVolumeView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html) , put it in a directory in `%PATH%` and wrote an Autohotkey script:

```
Volume_Up::
    Run, SoundVolumeView /ChangeVolume "AllAppVolume" +5
return

Volume_Down::
    Run, SoundVolumeView /ChangeVolume "AllAppVolume" -5
return
```

Credit where credit is due: this is a very slightly adjusted version of this reddit [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/hp4p6g/discord_volume_adjustment_using_nircmd_and/hqmh1c3/). The documentation said

> You can specify 'AllAppVolume' to change the volume of all applications at once. For example, in order to set the volume of all applications to 100%:
> SoundVolumeView.exe /SetVolume AllAppVolume 100

So I did.